# Not able to sync new layer in input app for QGIS

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

So I have been using the input app for QGIS to collect field data and I was able to do this successfully with two other layers. However I created a new layer for trash cans within QGIS on my computer and then tried to sync my project with the input app but I keep getting these error messages. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file `Input_Layers.gpkg` is stored outside of the Mergin Maps folder on your PC as reported by the validation warning. Therefore it is not synced to the Mergin Maps server and later to the Mergin Maps Input app. The file is not present on your phone and therefore it cannot be rendered on the phone.

To fix the issue, move the file Input_Layer.gpkg to the same folder as your `.qgz` file and resync to the phone (make sure you update both your QGIS project and move the file). Alternatively, you can use the package functionality of the plugin to create a valid package.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually just figure that out before I opened stack exchange today haha.